# How to correctly install custom package in Docker with docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, package, dockerfile

I am building a flask api and want to create a docker image of it. However, when I do docker-compose run (after build), it cannot find the module.

Error:

```
api_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
api_1  |   File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
api_1  |     from api.classify.classify import get_prediction
api_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- api
-- classify
--- classify.py
-- app.py
-- Dockerfile
-- requirements.txt
-- setup.py
```

The setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='image_api',
    keywords='',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

And the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /user/src/app
ENV PYTHONPATH=/api
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN python setup.py install
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

How do I fix this and what is best practice to install custom packages when building a Docker image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never over-write PYTHONPATH like that, nstead append your path, or the system will not find the installed Python packages.

You can do either of the following to make it work:

1. RUN export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/api"
2. ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/api"

Also your Dockerfile should be on api level, it wont be able to look for it in the present directory structure.

Comment: It already fails without Docker. When I try to install the package image_api with pip install . two things go wrong: it doesn't install requirements.txt and still cannot find the package.

Comment: Yeah it is because you are over writing the pythonpath. Change your command in dockerfile to one of the options I wrote. Let me know if it works

Comment: No, in a different project I just created. I have a setup.py and requirements.txt. But when I do pip install . it does install the local package but not the requirements. 

On top of that, the import function of the package still gives an error. 

P.S. I dont use PYTHONPATH here.

Comment: What was the error you got on changing your PYTHONPATH command to the one I mentioned. Did you try both the options?

Comment: I will try it now. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212910/discussion-between-niels-hoogeveen-and-uglycoder).